# What is reason for getting ProducerFencedException during producer.send?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Trying to load around 50K messages into KAFKA topic. In the beginning of few runs getting below exception but not all the time.

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Cannot execute transactional method because we are in an error state  
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager.maybeFailWithError(TransactionManager.java:784) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar:?]  
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager.beginAbort(TransactionManager.java:229) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar:?]  
at  org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.abortTransaction(KafkaProducer.java:679) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar:?]  
at myPackage.persistUpdatesPostAction(MyCode.java:??) ~[aKafka.jar:?]  
...  
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ProducerFencedException: Producer
attempted an operation with an old epoch. Either there is a newer producer with
the same transactionalId, or the producer's transaction has been expired by the
broker.
```

Code Block is below:

```
public void persistUpdatesPostAction(List<Message> messageList ) {
    if ((messageList == null) || (messageList.isEmpty())) {
        return;
    }
    logger.createDebug("Messages in batch(postAction) : "+ messageList.size());
    Producer<String,String> producer = KafkaUtils.getProducer(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    try {
        producer.beginTransaction();
        createKafkaBulkInsert1(producer, messageList, "Topic1");
        createKafkaBulkInsert2(producer, messageList, "Topic2");
        createKafkaBulkInsert3(producer, messageList, "Topic3");
        producer.commitTransaction();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        producer.abortTransaction();
        producer.close();
        KafkaUtils.removeProducer(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}

-----------

static Properties setPropertiesProducer() {
    Properties temp = new Properties();
    temp.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    temp.put("acks", "all");
    temp.put("retries", 1);
    temp.put("batch.size", 16384);
    temp.put("linger.ms", 5);
    temp.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
    temp.put("key.serializer",   "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    temp.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    return temp;
}

public static Producer<String, String> getProducer(String aThreadId) {
    if ((producerMap.size() == 0) || (producerMap.get(aThreadId) == null)) {
        Properties temp = producerProps;
        temp.put("transactional.id", aThreadId);
        Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(temp);
        producerMap.put(aThreadId, producer);
        producer.initTransactions();
        return producer;
    }
    return producerMap.get(aThreadId);
}

public static void removeProducer(String aThreadId) {
    logger.createDebug("Removing Thread ID :" + aThreadId);
    if (producerMap.get(aThreadId) == null)
        return;
    producerMap.remove(aThreadId);
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ProducerFencedException: Producer
> attempted an operation with an old epoch. Either there is a newer producer with
> the same transactionalId, or the producer's transaction has been expired by the
> broker.

This exception message is not very helpful.  I believe that it is *trying* to say that the broker no longer has any record of the transaction-id that is being sent by the client.  This can either be because:

- Someone else was using the same transaction-id and committed it already.  In my experience, this is less likely unless you are sharing transaction-ids between clients.  We ensure that our ids are unique using `UUID.randomUUID()`.
- The transaction timed out and was removed by broker automation.

In our case, we were hitting transaction timeouts every so often that generated this exception.  There are 2 properties that govern how long the broker will remember a transaction before aborting it and forgetting about it.

- `transaction.max.timeout.ms` -- A *broker* property that specifies the maximum number of milliseconds until a transaction is aborted and forgotten.  Default in many Kafka versions seems to be 900000 (15 minutes).  [Documentation from Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/) says:

  > The maximum allowed timeout for transactions. If a client’s requested transaction time exceeds this, then the broker will return an error in InitProducerIdRequest. This prevents a client from too large of a timeout, which can stall consumers reading from topics included in the transaction.
- `transaction.timeout.ms` -- A *producer client* property that sets the timeout in milliseconds when a transaction is created.  Default in many Kafka versions seems to be 60000 (1 minute).  Documentation from Kafka says:

  > The maximum amount of time in ms that the transaction coordinator will wait for a transaction status update from the producer before proactively aborting the ongoing transaction.

If the `transaction.timeout.ms` property set in the client exceeds the `transaction.max.timeout.ms` property in the broker, the producer will immediately throw something like the following exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Unexpected error in
InitProducerIdResponse The transaction timeout is larger than the maximum value
allowed by the broker (as configured by transaction.max.timeout.ms).
```

Comment: Thanks, this explanation is very useful than official document!

Comment: I was getting `ProducerFencedException`s, had no idea it was due to transaction timeouts. Thank you very much, saved me hours.

Answer (score 3):

> When running multiple instances of the application, `transactional.id`
> must be the same on all instances to satisfy fencing zombies when
> producing records on a listener container thread. However, when
> producing records using transactions that are **not** started by a
> listener container, the prefix has to be different on each instance.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#transaction-id-prefix

Answer (score 1):

There was race condition in my Producer initialization code. I have fixed by changing Producer map to the type ConcurrentHashMap to ensure thread safe.

Comment: ThreadLocal would have worked?

Comment: @AshikaUmangaUmagiliya May be, not tried it.

Answer (score 1):

I write a unit test to reproduce this, from this piece of Java code, you can easily understand how this happen by two same tansactional id.

```
  @Test
  public void SendOffset_TwoProducerDuplicateTrxId_ThrowException() {
    // create two producer with same transactional id
    Producer producer1 = KafkaBuilder.buildProducer(trxId, servers);
    Producer producer2 = KafkaBuilder.buildProducer(trxId, servers);

    offsetMap.put(new TopicPartition(topic, 0), new OffsetAndMetadata(1000));

    // initial and start two transactions
    sendOffsetBegin(producer1);
    sendOffsetBegin(producer2);

    try {
      // when commit first transaction it expected to throw exception
      sendOffsetEnd(producer1);

      // it expects not run here
      Assert.assertTrue(false);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      // it expects to catch the exception
      Assert.assertTrue(t instanceof ProducerFencedException);
    }
  }

  private void sendOffsetBegin(Producer producer) {
    producer.initTransactions();
    producer.beginTransaction();
    producer.sendOffsetsToTransaction(offsetMap, consumerGroup);
  }

  private void sendOffsetEnd(Producer producer) {
    producer.commitTransaction();
  }
```