# How to identify root cause of InvalidProducerEpochException/ProducerFencedException and how to fix it

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We have a Kafka streams spring boot application running in AWS.

```
springKafkaVersion: 2.8.7
apacheKafkaClientVersion: 3.0.2
confluentVersion: 5.5.5
```

Part of some performance testing in the middle of normal processing we noticed these two exceptions popping up in the logs and application become unhealthy and being restarted by AWS monitoring processes.

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidProducerEpochException: Producer attempted to produce with an old epoch.
Written offsets would not be recorded and no more records would be sent since the producer is fenced, indicating the task may be migrated out

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ProducerFencedException: There is a newer producer with the same transactionalId which fences the current one.
Failed to process stream task 1_3 since it got migrated to another thread already. Will trigger a new rebalance and close all tasks as zombies together.
```

Because the error description is not very clear about what was happening I search the web and google took me to these two posts:[What is reason for getting ProducerFencedException during producer.send?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53058715/what-is-reason-for-getting-producerfencedexception-during-producer-send) and [Why am I getting InvalidProducerEpochException when no producer is used?](https://forum.confluent.io/t/why-am-i-getting-invalidproducerepochexception-when-no-producer-is-used/3192/1). After reading those I was quite sure I will find the culprit in our Kafka configs but everything seems to be correct so I am running out of ideas. Here are our Kafka configurations:

**Producer config:**

```
acks = -1
batch.size = 1048576
bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
buffer.memory = 33554432
client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
client.id = my-app-StreamThread-1-producer
compression.type = none
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
delivery.timeout.ms = 2147483647
enable.idempotence = true
interceptor.classes = my.app.streams.interceptor.MyAppUpdatedInterceptor, my.app.streams.interceptor.CommandInterceptor, my.app.streams.interceptor.InProgressInterceptor]
key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
linger.ms = 50
max.block.ms = 60000
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
max.request.size = 1048576
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 30000
retries = 2147483647
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.jaas.config = null
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.login.class = null
sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
security.providers = null
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
ssl.engine.factory.class = null
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
ssl.keystore.key = null
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.certificates = null
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
transaction.timeout.ms = 10000
transactional.id = my-app.local-b8605317-d7b0-4da1-812b-4eb4bd188297-1
value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
```

**Consumer config:**

```
allow.auto.create.topics = false
auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
auto.offset.reset = latest
bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
check.crcs = true
client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
client.id = my-app-StreamThread-1-consumer
client.rack = 
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
enable.auto.commit = false
exclude.internal.topics = true
fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
fetch.min.bytes = 1
group.id = payments.stream.tlm.    my-app.local
group.instance.id = null
heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
interceptor.classes = [my.app.streams.interceptor.PaymentStatusUpdatedInterceptor, my.app.streams.interceptor.CommandInterceptor, my.app.streams.interceptor.InProgressInterceptor]
internal.leave.group.on.close = false
internal.throw.on.fetch.stable.offset.unsupported = true
isolation.level = read_committed
key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
max.poll.records = 500
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsPartitionAssignor]
receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 30000
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.jaas.config = null
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.login.class = null
sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
security.providers = null
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
session.timeout.ms = 10000
socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
ssl.engine.factory.class = null
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
ssl.keystore.key = null
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.certificates = null
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
```

**Streams Config:**

```
acceptable.recovery.lag = 10000
application.id = my-app.local
application.server = 
bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
buffered.records.per.partition = 1000
built.in.metrics.version = latest
cache.max.bytes.buffering = 10485760
client.id = payment-avro-formatter
commit.interval.ms = 100
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
default.deserialization.exception.handler = class my.app.streams.handler.FailOrContinueExceptionHandler
default.key.serde = null
default.list.key.serde.inner = null
default.list.key.serde.type = null
default.list.value.serde.inner = null
default.list.value.serde.type = null
default.production.exception.handler = class org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.DefaultProductionExceptionHandler
default.timestamp.extractor = class org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.FailOnInvalidTimestamp
default.value.serde = null
max.task.idle.ms = 0
max.warmup.replicas = 2
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
num.standby.replicas = 0
num.stream.threads = 6
poll.ms = 100
probing.rebalance.interval.ms = 600000
processing.guarantee = exactly_once_beta
receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
replication.factor = 3
request.timeout.ms = 40000
retries = 0
retry.backoff.ms = 100
rocksdb.config.setter = class my.app.streams.config.CustomRocksDBConfig
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
state.cleanup.delay.ms = 600000
state.dir = /tmp/kafka-streams
task.timeout.ms = 300000
topology.optimization = all
upgrade.from = null
window.size.ms = null
windowed.inner.class.serde = null
windowstore.changelog.additional.retention.ms = 86400000
```

Thank you in advance for your inputs/suggestions.

**UPDATE**
Analysing the logs at the broker side we could clearly see that there were some transactions that were timeout.