# Transactional KafkaProducer recover from timeout

Tags: java, kotlin, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, kafka-transactions-api

I am testing a Kotlin KafkaProducer application using Transactions and the possible scenarios:

- **Happy path: (working fine)**

  - begin transaction
  - producer.send
  - commit transaction
  - Assert consume.poll has a message
- **Exception on producer: (also working fine)**

  - begin transaction
  - producer.send
  - Throw RuntimeException
  - Abort transaction
  - Assert consume.poll has no messages
- **Timeout on producer: (Throws a ProducerFencedException)**

  - begin transaction
  - producer.send
  - Thread.Sleep (to let the transaction producer timeout)
  - Assert consume.poll has no messages (everything after this throws a ProducerFencedException)

I know the org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ProducerFencedException is thrown when the client is using a producer with an old Epoch (Zombie producer as said in Kafka literature). But my question is: how do I recover from a Timeout in a transactional producer? I am wondering if there is a way to let my producer to know that this producer is not valid and should be reset.

Thanks.

Here is my code (I omitted the successful cases)

- Main.kt

```
val producer = Producer()

fun main() {
    happyPath()
    timeoutTestSync()
    happyPath()
}

fun happyPath() {
    val consumer = Consumer()

    assert(consumer.readClean().isEmpty)
    assert(consumer.readDirty().isEmpty)

    producer.produceInTransaction("test${RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(1)}", false, false)

    assert(consumer.readClean().count() == 1)
}

fun timeoutTestSync() {
    val consumer = Consumer()

    assert(consumer.readClean().isEmpty)
    assert(consumer.readDirty().isEmpty)

    producer.produceInTransaction("test${RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(1)}", true, false)

    assert(consumer.readDirty().isEmpty)
    assert(consumer.readClean().isEmpty)
}
```

- Consumer.kt

```
private const val INPUT_TOPIC = "output"

class Consumer {

    private val consumer: KafkaConsumer<String, String> = createKafkaConsumer(false)
    private val dirtConsumer: KafkaConsumer<String, String> = createKafkaConsumer(true)

    private fun createKafkaConsumer(dirtRead:Boolean): KafkaConsumer<String, String> {
        val props:MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()

        props[ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = "localhost:9099"
        props[ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG] = "client-${RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(3)}"
        props[ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG] = "group-${RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(3)}"
        props[ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringDeserializer::class.java
        props[ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringDeserializer::class.java
        props[ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG] = true
        props[ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG] = "latest"
        if (dirtRead)
            props[ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG] = "read_uncommitted"
        else
            props[ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG] = "read_committed"

        val consumer:KafkaConsumer<String, String> = KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props)
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(INPUT_TOPIC))

        return consumer
    }

    fun readClean(): ConsumerRecords<String, String> {

        var records: ConsumerRecords<String, String> = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(10000))

        return records
    }

    fun readDirty(): ConsumerRecords<String, String> {

        var records: ConsumerRecords<String, String> = dirtConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(10000))

        return records
    }
}
```

- Producer.kt

```
private const val OUTPUT_TOPIC = "output"

class Producer {
    private val producer: KafkaProducer<String, String> = createKafkaProducer()

    private fun createKafkaProducer(): KafkaProducer<String, String> {
        val props = Properties()
        props[ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = "localhost:9099"
        props[ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG] = "true"
        props[ProducerConfig.TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT_CONFIG] = 5000
        props[ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG] = "prod-${RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(3)}-"
        props[ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"
        props[ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"
        val producerOut:KafkaProducer<String,String> = KafkaProducer(props)
        producerOut.initTransactions()
        return producerOut
    }


    fun produceInTransaction(message:String, delay:Boolean, exception:Boolean) {
        try {
            producer.beginTransaction()

            val x = producer.send(ProducerRecord<String, String>(OUTPUT_TOPIC, "1", message))

            when {
                delay -> {
                    Thread.sleep(10000)
                }
                exception -> {
                    throw RuntimeException("Simulated exception")
                }
            }

            producer.commitTransaction()
        }
        catch (e:RuntimeException) {
            producer.abortTransaction()
            println("Exception in transaction: ${e}")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you expect your transactions to timeout, you would need to handle `ProducerFencedException`. The producer cannot by itself know that it has expired and the exception occurs when it tries to commit the ongoing transaction. You could handle the exception in your code - initialise a new producer object and retry with the new producer.

That being said, if you have configured your settings correctly - this should be a very rare case scenario. You could reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53058715/what-is-reason-for-getting-producerfencedexception-during-producer-send) thread to see various configuration options.